# postgreSQL rake db:setup revert back data recovery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, backup, data-recovery

I'm working on an application which runs on PostgreSQL. While I was modifying the schema by creating another table, I, unfortunately, ran `rake db:setup` and all my data was deleted. I manually didnt take any backup. Is there any possible way to rollback or to get the records back?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh no, that is not possible. so there is no rails way you could get back your data.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no", but you could try your luck with [pg_dirtyread](https://github.com/omniti-labs/pgtreats/tree/master/contrib/pg_dirtyread).